# Angular2 lifecycle hook for fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

Is there any lifecycle hook, which tells you if all the content is loaded? I'm having a site, which has several asynchronously working components. So the components are not ready at the same time. To avoid a strange appearance of the site, I'd like to put a kind of loading banner in place. But obviously, I need to know when I can disable the banner again.

Thanks for any suggestions or idea!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ngAfterViewInit()
```

of the `AppComponent`

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/AfterContentInit-class.html

This won't cover components added by the router or non-Angular libraries.

Comment: No, there are no lifecycle hooks that consider async callbacks. You need to chain your async callbacks yourself by passing `Observable`s or `Promise`s to callers for them to be able to `.subscribe(...)` or call `.then(...)`

Comment: That's what I thought too. The question implied it.

Comment: I have this use case, where I have a parent with multiple children and they may have also children. Now I would like to display a kind of loading indicator, but how should be the one removing the indicator? I guess it would be easy, if I know I always have all my child components loaded. But depending on the entry you are looking at, one child component might not be used. So how can I make sure that **all** my child components are loaded? `ngAfterViewInit()` just takes care of an individual component, isn't it?

Comment: Child components are rendered before `ngAfterViewInit()` is called, otherwise it wouldn't be "after view init" because the childrens **are** the view. If you have something like `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` with async loaded data, the parents `ngAfterViewInit()` will be called before these items are rendered though.

Comment: In that case I have to think of way to get somehow else to what I want to achieve.